# As portas "fecham" ou "se fecham"?

Tags: verbos-intransitivos

O metrô do Rio de Janeiro tem no sistema de som as seguintes frases:  "atenção, portas se abrindo" e "atenção, portas se fechando".  Já o elevador de um prédio por onde circulo com frequência, tem os seguintes avisos: portas abrindo, elevador subindo/descendo" e "portas fechando, elevador subindo/descendo".  Estão as duas formas corretas?   Caso estejam, há preferência de uma sobre a outra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Fechar* pertence à classe dos **verbos de alternância causativa-incoativa** . Estes verbos têm uma variedade transitiva causativa e uma variedade incoativa, que é intransitiva e inacusativa.

Esta classe não tem um comportamento homogéneo em relação ao uso do clítico anticausativo *se*. Alguns verbos requerem-no, para outros é opcional, e com outros o clítico não pode nunca ser usado. Pablo Ribeiro dá na sua tese de mestrado [*A Alternância Causativa no Português do Brasil: a Distribuição do Clítico se*](http://www.lume.ufrgs.br/bitstream/handle/10183/24047/000743616.pdf) estes três exemplos (pág. 67):

> (1a) A menina fechou a janela.
>   (1b) A janela fechou. / A janela se fechou.
>   (2a) A frente fria diminuiu a temperatura.
>   (2b) A temperatura diminui. / *A temperatura se diminuiu.
>   (3a) Os gritos apavoraram a molecada.
>   (3b) *A molecada apavorou. / A molecada apavorou-se.

Segundo o mesmo autor, no português brasileiro hodierno, o clítico *se* é obrigatório apenas em casos em que o uso é necessário para evitar ambiguidade, como verbos em que ambos os argumentos da forma causativa podem ser animados.

Em Portugal, o uso de *se* é muito mais comum, o que não quer dizer que não se ouçam por aí frases como *a porta fechou sozinha*.

Num texto cuidado, eu recomendaria o uso de *se*. Obras de referência, como o *Dicionário de Verbos e Regimes* de Franscisco Fernandes, apenas registam a acepção *encerrar-se* para a forma pronominal. Para a forma intransitiva encontramos somente *cicatrizar*, *tornar-se denso/escuro* e *dar por findo o serviço/encerrar o expediente*.

Comment: Então as frases marcadas com asteriscos são consideradas corretas devido à ambiguidade?

Comment: @stafusa Não, o asterisco marca as frases agramaticais. A ambiguidade a que o autor da tese se refere é a de verbos como ferir ou preocupar, que, quando usados transitivamente podem ter os dois argumentos ocupados por entidades animadas, por exemplo _o João feriu a Maria_. Nesse casos, _se_ tende a ser obrigatório na versão incoativa: _o João feriu-se_.

Comment: OK, assim fica claro porque você também prefere com "se".

Answer (score 1):

Ambos são corretos [1], mas para uso numa frase mais completa e em linguagem formal, eu diria que `fechar`, com esse significado, soa melhor com o pronome. Comparada à do metrô, a mensagem no elevador pode ter um sentido ainda mais 'mecânico', de notificação de status: "portas: fechando".

[1] Para o significado mais amplo (3: *Pôr(-se) sobre outro de modo que ajuste e fique unido*) o [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=fechar) confirma a necessidade do pronome na ausência de objeto, mas permite também o uso não pronominal numa accepção bem mais delimitada (25: *Entrar na esquadria*).